# How to display a Core Data entity in UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I managed to build a little Core Data database that looks like this:
I've got one or more entities called 'User' having some attributes like firstName, lastName, avatarImage, birthday...

Another attribute of this 'User' is a to-many relationship to entities called 'Account'.
To display this content I set up a UIViewController with UITableView split in two sections, the first one for all the general information (firstName, lastName) and the second one for the NSSet of accounts (one cell per account, just an overview of them).

So far, so good :)

My problem now is: How can I retrieve the basic information for the first section without having to manually add them to a dictionary or array that, for example, has a 'count' property which is essential for building the table view. Additionally it must be legal to have a nil value  for some of the entity's attributes.
This table view only needs to display this single entity, which is passed to the class as a property (self.userEntity ...)

Hope you understand what I mean and have some ideas :)

Thx in advance

Dario

Answer (score 0):

So you have an array or set of 'Account's, you have 'User' which has a to-many relationship with 'Account' and you want efficiently to get to the set of 'User's that has any of the nominated accounts?

The key-value coding solution would be something like:

```
NSSet *setOfAccounts = ...whatever...;

// assuming the to-one relationship from 'account' to 'user' is named 'user'
NSSet *setOfUsers = [setOfAccounts valueForKey:@"user"];
```

You could also use a Core Data query if it's easier for you to supply that somewhere, though I'm unable to come up with a solution that doesn't involve a subquery:

```
// assuming the to-many relationship from 'user' to 'account' is named 'accounts'
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
               @"SUBQUERY(accounts, $x, %@ contains $x).@count > 0", accounts]
```

That'd likely be slower than the key-value coding approach. If performance is an issue I'd recommend you get the set of users using the KVC approach, then perform a fetch request on `self in ...` to fault in all the relevant users.

The issue on subqueries is that `NSPredicate` has `contains` but nothing for 'is contained in', so you can't directly flip it around to be something like:

```
"any accounts isContainedIn %@", accounts
```

Which would otherwise likely compile down to more efficient SQL. If whatever your original predicate was is adaptable then it'd definitely be more efficient to formulate it as an any operation, so e.g. if it was:

```
/* accounts where ... */
"accountDate > %@", someDateInThePast
```

Then the fastest query for users would be:

```
"any accounts.accountDate > %@", someDateInThePast
```

Sadly I don't think 'any' has any suitable syntax for applying conditions to multiple fields at once so if your query on accounts is non-trivial then you'd need to fall back on the SUBQUERY approach if key-value coding isn't acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested in adding table view cell, and editing/deleting them. You should definitely take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBrkavVJsw0) i used this tutorial twice, and it got me up to speed with core data very fast! He is a great teacher! Its a 4 part series, he teaches you how to load entities on different views etc!